# I'm trying to use something other than a boolean function

Tags: c++

P is one-dimensional array of integers. Write a C++ function to efficiently search for a data VAL from P. If VAL is present in the array then the function should return the position of the value otherwise display the value doesn’t exist.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool lsearch(int Arr[], int s, int VAL);

int main()
{
    int Arr[100],n,val;
    bool found;

    cout<<"Enter number of elements you want to insert ";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>Arr[i];
    }

    cout<<"Enter the number you want to search ";
    cin>>val;

    found=lsearch(Arr,n,val);

    if(found)
        cout<<"\nItem found";
    else
        cout<<"\nItem not found";


    return 0;
}

bool lsearch(int Arr[], int s, int VAL)
{
    for(int I=0; I<s; I++)
    {
        if(Arr[I]==VAL)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm asked to use something other than boolean like void found: i tried void with return at end but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is to return the position.so, you can do  in the below way.

```
int lsearch(int Arr[], int s, int VAL)
    {
        for(int I=0; I<s; I++)
        {
            if(Arr[I]==VAL)
                return I;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: so should i still use the boolean found for the                                      if(found)
        cout<<"\nItem found";
    else
        cout<<"\nItem not found";
or i can just say something else like if the statement is 0 return item is found and if its 1 or -1 retuen item is not found

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to return the *position* of the value, so `bool` and `void` are both the wrong choice - it should be an integer of some sort.
Since the position must be a non-negative integer, you can return a signed integer and indicate failure by returning a negative number. (`-1` is the "normal" choice, so choose that.)
Then you make the output depend on whether the result is negative or not.

The relevant part of your `main` would look like

```
int position = lsearch(Arr,n,val);
if (position >= 0)
{
    cout << "Item found at position " << position << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Item not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: for the first answer by MSD so should i still use the boolean found for the if(found) cout<<"\nItem found"; else cout<<"\nItem not found"; or i can just say something else like if the statement is 0 return item is found and if its 1 or -1 retuen item is not found